# AutoLayout crashes if changing UILabel`s text

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, xcode7.3

So, I making a UItableViewCells with custom action menu, thats opens sliding from right by tapping cell, and everywhere using constraints to layout it. And if im trying change label when buttons is shown cell by itself weird jumps to start position.

Here`s some images:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGIYH.png) after opening actions.

then tapping on green button must change colour and text, but cell suddenly jumps, and it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFYIe.png).

Code for cell sliding is:

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        if !self.state {
            self.contentView.layer.position.x -= self.actionViewWidth                       // contentView
            self.viewWithTag(5)?.layer.position.x -= self.actionViewWidth                   // actionView
            self.logoImageView.layer.position.x += self.actionViewWidth - self.padding * 2  // imageView
            self.nameLabel.alpha = self.hide                                                // nameLabel
            self.cellarLabel.alpha = self.show                                              // cellarLabel
            self.state = true

        } else {
            self.contentView.layer.position.x += self.actionViewWidth                       // contentView
            self.viewWithTag(5)?.layer.position.x += self.actionViewWidth                   // actionView
            self.logoImageView.layer.position.x -= self.actionViewWidth - self.padding * 2  // imageView
            self.nameLabel.alpha = self.show                                                // nameLabel
            self.cellarLabel.alpha = self.hide                                              // cellarLabel

            self.state = false
        }
        }
```

Here is animation thats have to change text:

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.15, animations: {
        self.imageView.alpha = 0
        self.subLabel.alpha = 0
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.91, blue:0.11, alpha:1.0)
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (_) -> Void in
            self.subAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor(red:0.61, green:0.61, blue:0.61, alpha:1.0)
            self.subAttributes[NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName] = NSUnderlineStyle.StyleNone.rawValue
            self.subLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Waiting", attributes: self.subAttributes) // this line crashes the contsraints
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.15) {
                self.subLabel.alpha = 1
                self.label.alpha = 1
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that a tap on the cell causes it to slide left?

Comment: @ryantxr Yeah, is like swipe in iOS mail app with actions, but with tap